# Laravel Mutators with Constructor?

Tags: laravel

Ill have a problem because my mutators never get called when ill use an constructor:

Like this:

```
function __construct() {
    $this->attributes['guid'] = Uuid::generate(4)->string;
}

public function setDateAttribute($date) {
    dd($date); // Never gets called
}
```

Ill already found out, that the mutators would ne be called when ill use an constructor, so i should use:

```
public function __construct(array $attributes = array()){
    parent::__construct($attributes);
    $this->attributes['guid'] = Uuid::generate(4)->string;
}

public function setDateAttribute($date) {
    dd($date); // now its getting called
}
```

But so ill get the following error:

```
array_key_exists() expects parameter 2 to be array, null given
```

But i dont know where? Can anyone help me out how to create a default value (like a UUID) for a specific column, and use mutators in the same class?

**Edit: Thanks Martin Bean for your help, but i am now getting the following error:**

```
Cannot declare class App\Uuid because the name is already in use
```

I have tried:

Creating a File called "Uuid.php" in /app/ -> /app/Uuid.php

With this content:

```
<?php namespace App;

use Webpatser\Uuid\Uuid;

trait Uuid
{
    public static function bootUuid()
    {
        static::creating(function ($model) {
            $model->uuid = Uuid::generate(4)->string();
        });
    }
}
```

Changed my Model to:

```
<?php namespace App;
use Carbon\Carbon;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;


class Task extends Model {

    use \App\Uuid;
```

Thank you very much!

**Edit 2:**

Ill tried it this way:

```
class Task extends Model {

    protected $table = 'tasks';

    protected $fillable = ['..... 'date', 'guid'];

    public function setGuidAttribute($first=false){
    if($first) $this->attributes['guid'] = Uuid::generate(4)->string;
}
```

TaskController:

```
public function store() {

    $input = Request::all();
    $input['guid'] = true;
    Task::create($input);

    return redirect('/');

}
```

Works fine, but when ill use:

```
public function setDateAttribute(){
    $this->attributes['date'] = date('Y-m-d', $date);
}
```

In Task.php ill get:

```
Undefined variable: date
```

Comment: Please why must you use a construct? What are you trying to archive?

Comment: I would like to set an UUID to a specific column for every new object

Comment: Then you don't need a constructor to do that

Comment: And how can i solve that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

EDITED:

based on your comment:

> i would like to set a field on first insert

```
use Uuid; //please reference the correct namespace to Uuid 

class User extends Model{

   protected $fillable = [
      'first_name',
      'email',
      'guid' //add guid to list of your fillables
   ]

    public function setGuidAttribute($first=false){
        if($first) $this->attributes['guid'] = Uuid::generate(4)->string;
    }
 }
```

Later:

```
 $user = User::create([
    'guid' => true, //setAttribute will handle this
    'first_name' => 'Digitlimit',
    'email"  => my@email.com
 ]);

dd($user->guid);
```

NB: Remove the __construct() method from your model

Comment: Thanks for your answer: But i am getting now the error: undefined index 'date' (but the parameter should be here, if i check my request i have a date parameter) - ill copied my code to my question as edit.

Comment: please remove this `protected $attributes;`. its overwriting some attributes

Comment: Thanks - done this, but the function getGuidAttribute never gets called

Comment: i tested it and its working. let me add the full code

Comment: is Uuid a laravel package ? if yes please may I have the github url

Comment: One more thing are trying to Set or Get uuid field in database? Perhaps to assign a unique ID to a user or something?

Comment: i would like to set a field on first insert.

Comment: then all you need is setUuidAttribute where Uuid is a field that exists in a db table

Comment: Will that be called WITHOUT getting the "uuid" field from the form?

Comment: I don't quite understand your application flow? are you trying to get this value from a submitted form? If nope, then `uuid` field in your database table will be automatically updated when you create a new record for a user... remember to set `$first` to `true`

Comment: No no, i want to create a UUID for a specific row when i insert a new Object. So the user is not able to change this field, it should just get an UUID as default value. Where should i set $first? can u provide me an example here pls? Thanks for your new example - and i can combine this with standard mutators?

Comment: thats what exactly am doing here `$user = User::create([
    'guid' => true, //setAttribute will handle this
    'first_name' => 'Digitlimit',
    'email"  => my@email.com
 ]);` have you tried the code in my answer? what does your migration looks like?

Comment: I already tried it - and it works fine, but when ill try to use any other Mutator, ill get an error that this field is not defined (pls see my Edit)

Comment: please can you share the code for the model where you are doing this

Comment: You are too quick, thanks for helping me out! Maybe you have a few minutes in chat?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/80392/discussion-between-digitlimit-and-derdida).

Answer (score 1):

**EDIT:** Whilst the below approach is still valid for adding “concerns” to Laravel models, Laravel since version 9.x has shipped with its own trait for generating UUIDs for models. Docs: https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/eloquent#uuid-and-ulid-keys

Mutators are called when you try and set a property on the model—they’re invoked via the `__get` magic method. If you manually assign a property in a method or constructor, then no mutators will ever be called.

Regardless, you should not be creating constructors on Eloquent model classes. This could interfere with how Eloquent models are “booted”.

If you need to set an UUID on a model then I’d suggest using a trait that has its own boot method:

```
namespace App\Models\Concerns;

trait HasUuid
{
    protected static function bootHasUuid(): void
    {
        static::creating(function (Model $model) {
            $model->uuid = Str::uuid()->toString();
        });
    }
}
```

You apply the trait to your model…

```
use App\Models\Concerns;

class SomeModel extends Model
{
    use HasUuid;
}
```

…and now each time a model is created, a UUID will be generated and stored in the database with your model in the `uuid` column.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Ive never used traits before, where should i save them? Like a Controller? Otherwise i guess i need to change the name or, because "UUID is already used by the UUID Class)? - Could the trait also be in the same Class File, or do i need a new one?

Comment: You should only have one class/trait/interface per file (otherwise auto-loading doesn’t work). And if you use namespaces, then it’s totally acceptable to have two classes named the same. As for where to save the file, that’s up to you. I wouldn’t save it in the controller directory though because they’re not related to controllers; you’re applying them to models.